# How to fix "Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled" error for my npm package

Tags: reactjs, npm, babeljs, npm-publish

I am currently working on publishing a npm package for ReactJs. And everything works fine on my local machine but when I try to use the published the package, I keep getting this error

```
Add @babel/preset-react (https://git.io/JfeDR) to the presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation. Failed to compile.



Add @babel/preset-react (https://git.io/3feDR) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation. If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx (https://git.io/vb4yA) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.
```

I have a html button inside the return part of the package and I also tried doing what the error said but I still couldn't make it work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.